# resize image background of div

Tags: css, image, resize

I found [This](http://cssglobe.com/post/1367/creating-and-styling-resizable-buttons) tutorial for resize background of `button`. i change this for auto width resize images of `DIV` but This not Worked. How to fix this ?! i need to resize images background of div .
Original Demo : [HERE](http://cssglobe.com/lab/button/) 
Edited Demo : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/33m4p/) 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `button em` to `.home em` in your stylesheet. If you want it to shrink to the size of the text add `display:inline-block` to the `.home` rules.

Comment: i changes this. but this not fixed my problem ! see new edited http://jsfiddle.net/33m4p/2/

Comment: it's working fine, so either you have a browser-specific issue or you haven't clearly defined the problem. What I see is a button that fills the width of the page with rounded edges on both sides. That's what `width:auto` / `display:block` is telling it to do. If you actually want it to shrink around the text then you need to be using `display:inline-block` on the div.

Answer (score 0):

The button image is not wide enough to cover your entire `div`. Either make the image wider (edit it and re-upload), or make the div narrower.

Comment: You see Original  Demo ? i dont edit button images. please see original demo

Comment: Yes, the original demo uses elements that are smaller in width than the image, and therefore they work.